# Can I use only one user type?

Tags: sylius

The standard edition sets up two user types; admin users and shop users.  I'd like to have only one user definition for the entire application; is it possible to remove the admin users and have all the user accounts under one user type (with proper role mapping and ACL)?

Comment: Can i ask why you want to remove Admin users? No one will be able to access the admin area without that permission. Or are you hoping to give everyone that same access which means they will be allowed to access the admin? the RbacBundle handles all permissions so you might need to look in there

Comment: The aim was to not have two types of user accounts on the site.  Sylius Standard, specifically the CoreBundle, pretty much forces you to have two different user object types.  Our preference was to not require separate accounts for the frontend and the backend.  We've since shifted to starting from Symfony Standard and pulling only the Sylius bundles we need to add the needed shop functionality for this project.

Comment: Ah ok, the sylius project (not sylius standard) uses the users table and the customers table. But all login details are stored in the users table, and a user can have a customer but not required. Good luck with it all. It's a great code base but i found it quite tricky to begin with

Comment: Ignore my comment, i hadn't updated to the latest version which does indeed split the users table out. You might be able to change the user provider in the security.yml to look in the shop_user table instead. Then you'd just need to add the admin role to the necessary shop users